# Entity framework 4 CRUD creating errors

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 3 related tables in my database.

Farm ----> FarmCrops <----- Crops

I'm trying to update the a farm entity with a collection of crops but am running into problems. I've been working on this with no success for hours now so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The error I'm receiving is this:

> The object cannot be attached because
>   it is already in the object context.
>   An object can only be reattached when
>   it is in an unchanged state.

My update logic is as follows (my apologies for the large amount of code. I'd just like to be as clear as possible):

```
            bool isNew = false;
            Farm farm;

            // Insert or update logic.
            if (viewModel.Farm.FarmId.Equals(Guid.Empty))
            {
                farm = new Farm
                {
                    FarmId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    RatingSum = 3,
                    RatingVotes = 1
                };
                isNew = true;
            }
            else
            {
                farm = this.ReadWriteSession
                       .Single<Farm>(x => x.FarmId == viewModel.Farm.FarmId);

            }

            // Edit/Add the properties.
            farm.Name = viewModel.Farm.Name;
            farm.Owner = viewModel.Farm.Owner;
            farm.Address = viewModel.Farm.Address;
            farm.City = viewModel.Farm.City;
            farm.Zip = viewModel.Farm.Zip;
            farm.WebAddress = viewModel.Farm.WebAddress;
            farm.PhoneNumber = viewModel.Farm.PhoneNumber;
            farm.Hostel = viewModel.Farm.Hostel;
            farm.Details = viewModel.Farm.Details;
            farm.Latitude = viewModel.Farm.Latitude;
            farm.Longitude = viewModel.Farm.Longitude;
            farm.Weather = viewModel.Farm.Weather;

            // Add or update the crops.
            string[] cropIds = Request.Form["crop-token-input"].Split(',');
            List<Crop> allCrops = this.ReadWriteSession.All<Crop>().ToList();

            if (!isNew)
            {
                // Remove all previous crop/farm relationships.
                farm.Crops.Clear();
            }

            // Loop through and add any crops.
            foreach (Crop crop in allCrops)
            {
                foreach (string id in cropIds)
                {
                    Guid guid = Guid.Parse(id);
                    if (crop.CropId == guid)
                    {
                        farm.Crops.Add(crop);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (isNew)
            {
                this.ReadWriteSession.Add<Farm>(farm);
            }
            else
            {
                this.ReadWriteSession.Update<Farm>(farm);
            }
            this.ReadWriteSession.CommitChanges();
```

My update code within the ReadWriteSession is simple enough (`GetSetName<T>` just returns the types name from it's PropertyInfo.):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Updates an instance of the specified type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The instance of the given type to add.</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of entity for which to provide the method.</typeparam>
    public void Update<T>(T item) where T : class, new()
    {
        this.context.AttachTo(this.GetSetName<T>(), item);
        this.context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(item, EntityState.Modified);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding existing `Crop` objects (from the `allCrops` list) to the new `Farm`. When you connect a new entity to an existing one, the new entity automatically gets attached to the context. Therefore you get the error when you try to attach the `Farm` to the context the second time.

The `Add<Farm>(farm)` statement in your code is not even necessary to connect the `Farm` to the context, and if you have an existing `Farm` that is loaded from the context, it is already attached to the context.

The whole of your `if (isNew)` statement is unnecessary. Entity framework tracks object state itself, so you don't need to set the modified state.

Answer (score 3):

you don't have to attach the "farm" object at the end, because it's already attached as modified when you change one of its properties. try removing the else statement at the end:

```
if (isNew)
{
   this.ReadWriteSession.Add<Farm>(farm);
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: If it were possible to mark more than one answer I would. I've upvoted yours anyway... I think you were beaten by about 30 seconds. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your update method. You can't attach the `Farm` instance because you have loaded it from the same context so it is already attached and you don't need to call your `Update` at all because changes to attached objects are tracked automatically.

Comment: If it were possible to mark more than one answer I would. I've upvoted yours anyway... Thanks!